# Virtial machine that feels native?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtual-desktop

Is it possible to have a fully functional native OS desktop experience (Windows) on a virtual machine that doesn't feel like it's a guest OS? Kinda like Virtualbox but once it's loaded you can't tell it's just a guest OS sitting on a "physical OS". Basically a full OS experience that can withstand reboots and stuff, but it's an image behind the scenes.

I ask because I don't want to do a reformat on my primary Windows desktop in case of a major hardware change in the future. Is what I'm thinking doable?

Comment: Could you clarify what, specifically, _doesn't_ feel like a native OS when using a VM?

Comment: You mean like Parallels ‘coherence ‘ mode? https://kb.parallels.com/en/4670

Comment: @grawity I actually only used VirtualBox, so far it feels like a small window. Maybe I don't know how to use it properly. Do you recommend a different software? I want a "dual boot" feel in a guest OS.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not quite. I don't like to mix 2 OS. Basically I want to boot my OS image as if it was a host machine. Then in the future if I upgrade the PC, I simply copy the OS image on the new PC then boot it as if nothing's change in the hardware, possible?